# YUI after appending body, on('click') even doesn't work

Tags: javascript, yui

Hello I have been trying to build my DOM with html templates and js, but i had problem with this code.;

```
 YUI().use(
          'aui-modal',
          'stylesheet',
          'aui-io-request',
          function(Y) {
              var officers;
              Y.io.request('https://demo6120867.mockable.io/cmdOfficers', {
                   method: 'GET',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   on: {
                       success:function() {

                           officers = this.get('responseData').officers;
                           for(var i=0;i<officers.length;i++){
                          var template = Y.one("#officerTemplate")
                           var officerName = template.one("#officerName");
                           var officerDepartment = template.one("#department");
                           var officerId;
                           officerName.set('innerText',officers[i].officerName);

                           officerDepartment.set('innerText',officers[i].department);
                           var buttonHolder = template.one("#action_buttons")
                           var officerButtons = buttonHolder.all(".hp");

                           console.log("Officer Buttons")
                           console.log(officerButtons[0]);
                           console.log("Officer Buttons all");
                           console.log(officerButtons);
                           officerButtons.each(function(buttonNode,index){
                               console.log(buttonNode);
                               officerId = officers[i].id;
                               var data = buttonNode.getData("id");
                               // This will not get store in dom.
                               buttonNode.setData("id",i+"_"+index);
                               buttonNode.setData("officer_id",officerId);
                               console.log(buttonNode.getData("id"));
                           });
                           var bodyNode = Y.one(document.body);
                           var newItem = Y.Node.create(template.getContent()).setStyle("display","block");;
                           newItem.set('id','officer_'+i);
                           bodyNode.append(newItem);
                           // when we have template we can insert our data and append to dom.
                           }
                        }
                   }
             });
```

The last line of code as you see is appending body so i am expecting when i call

```
 Y.all(".hp").on("click",function(e){
                 console.log("clicked");
```

click function doesn't work, how can i workaround this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might be a perfect case for [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Since the elements in questions are not in the `DOM` yet when the event is bound.

```
Y.one(document.body).delegate("click", function(e) {
                 console.log("clicked");
                }, ".hp");
```

The document body can be replaced with the closest parent that contains the `.hp` elements.

https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: I was doing exact same with jquery but now i get error like this : TypeError: t.apply is not a function, also this error's source is "combo.php:10:1732"

Comment: I fixed the problem, thanks you should use '.hp' instead of Y.all('.hp')